# Show unordered list's bullet points when display:table

Tags: css, html-lists

When I try to get my list item's text to wrap with an indent so there is no text under the bullet points of the list my bullet points disappear.

I have set up the list's CSS this way:

```
ul
{
  display:table;
}

li
{
  display:table-row;
}
```

How do I get my bullet points to show again?

Thank you in advance!

[edited for clarity]

Comment: What do you mean by "wrap in line with the bullet points of the list?"

Comment: I wanted the text that went to the next line to have an indent so there was no text under the bullet point.

Comment: Like this? http://jsfiddle.net/2SbG5/

Comment: That's the solution!  The "display:table-row;" is superfluous.  Please make it an answer and I will tick it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting `display:table-row` you remove the default list bullets, and there is (in CSS as currently defined and implemented) no way to get them back (if you wish to keep that `display:table-row`—it’s not obvious why you are using it).

However, you can produce markers of your own, using generated content. e.g.

```
li:before {
  content: "\2022";
  padding-right: 0.5em;
}
```

The notation `\2022` stands for U+2022 BULLET “•”. Usually it does not look the same as default list bullets, but similar. You might wish to experiment with different fonts (you can set the font of the pseudo-element different from the font in the item contents).

Comment: Sorry Jukka K, Explosion Pills answered first.  But you are absolutely correct! Thank you.

Comment: This is what I used: `ul {
            display: table;
            padding-left: 0;
        }
        li {
            display: table-row;
        }
        li::before {
            content: "•";
            display: block;
            margin-left: 0.25in;
            width: 0.25in;
        }`. The effect was quite satisfactory!

Answer (score 0):

You need `display: list-item` for the bullet to display.  Remove the `display: table-row` from the `<li>` elements.  Not only does it remove the bullets, `list-item` wraps the content properly anyway.